# Problems collecting comet medals in Super Mario Galaxy 2

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I try to collect the comet medals that I missed in galaxies where I've already got a star.
I collect it, but at the end, the medal is not stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You must finish the level (ie get the star) to save the comet medal you collected.